# Trying to get a JSONObect to tokener help please ?

Tags: android

I need to get some information from an JSONArray and i thought tokener would do it. Heres my code

```
try{
            JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
            for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){
                String data = jArray.getString(i);
                    JSONObject json_data = (JSONObject)new JSONTokener (data).nextValue();
                    String query = json_data.getString("name");
                    JSONArray locations = json_data.getJSONArray("locations");

                    //Get an output to the screen
                    txt.setText(query); 
                    }
```

The actual array is filling with data from my database via http post.

Field names are `id`, `name`, `servings`, `description`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your JSONArray contains JSON objects, than you could do:

```
 try{
     JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
     for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){
         JSONObject json_data = jArray.optJSONObject(i)

         // making sure we got JSON object
         if(json_data == null) continue;

         String query = json_data.getString("name");
         JSONArray locations = json_data.getJSONArray("locations");

         //Get an output to the screen
         txt.setText(query); 
}
```

Comment: Hi peter i tried your method and it still doesn't seem to print any data out. I eventually want to be able to print out different columns of data into a list. Im not sure if my code is returning a result how do i check.

Answer (score 0):

Or you could use Gson to handle JSON (de)serialization. You don't have to write custom code for this. http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/